# How can I shorten this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the non-saying title, but I have a question on how to shorten a piece of jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#profile1").click(function() {
        $("#profile1").addClass("focused");
        $("#profile2").removeClass("focused");
        $("#profile3").removeClass("focused");
    });
    $("#profile2").click(function() {
        $("#profile1").removeClass("focused");
        $("#profile2").addClass("focused");
        $("#profile3").removeClass("focused");
    });
    $("#profile3").click(function() {
        $("#profile1").removeClass("focused");
        $("#profile2").removeClass("focused");
        $("#profile3").addClass("focused");
    });
});
```

For what I can see, a toggleClass wouldn't do it, since I can press that object two times in a row and therefore make multiple objects being focused at the same time, while I'm looking for some kind of a switch, where only one object can be in focus (i.e. have the class 'focused') at a time.

This is me being kind of a beginner, but I'm guessing I should involve 'this' somewhere, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance! You guys rock!

Comment: Give them an overall class, then target it. For example `$(".profile")`

Comment: Also, you can use `$(this)` inside the click event.

Comment: Use radio buttons? That's what they do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the class from all of them, then add it to the targeted one only. Also, use a single event handler only and reference the event target dynamically.

```
$(function() {
    var $profiles = $("#profile1, #profile2, #profile3");
    $profiles.click(function(e) {
        $profiles.removeClass("focused");
        $(this).addClass("focused"); // or use `e.target` instead of `this`
    });
});
```

You might also use a class `.profile` instead of ids to select the elements now.

Comment: That's great! How about if I would like to change a completely other div, that also has three objects (let's say images). I want one of them to be "focused" together with the according profile number, i.e. when I click #profile1 it get's the class "focused", but I also want an image with the id #id1 to receive the same class.

Comment: Then you need to use some sort of mapping from the clickable elements to the image elements. This can be a static table in your code (key-value-map: an object), a dynamically built property on your profiles, or even an attribute referencing the image selector. E.g. you can read the number from `this.id`, prepend `#id`, and use that as a selector.